# Office (JS) Outlook add-in uses different hostname for EWS and token

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js

I try to bind to an Exchange Webservice (EWS) using a bearer token retrieved from Outlook through the Office-js platform (using the EWS java API library). I'm getting the following in the HTTP response from Exchange though

```
x-ms-diagnostics: 2000003;reason="The hostname component of the audience claim value is invalid. Expected 'exchange2013.xxxxxx.com'. Actual 'webmail.xxxxxx.com'.";error_category="invalid_resource"
```

When I ask Outlook what the EWS url is via:

```
Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl
```

I get the exchange2013.xxxxxx.com address. The token I retrieve via

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()
```

contains the webmail.xxxxxx.com address (this is visible when I Base64 decode the token string). What exactly is going wrong here? How come the EWS URL and token domain are different?

Comment: Maybe it seems like a access scope or permission issue. you could refer to the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026016/office365-api-returns-the-hostname-component-of-the-audience-claim-value-https

Comment: Are the internal / external EWS URLs on your server different? If so are they both being returned in AutoDiscover? What client version of Outlook are you using? (Outlook Web Access, Outlook 2013, Outlook 2016 etc?) Also what is the version number if using the desktop version? (i.e. 16.0.11010.20000)